# Why am I getting a border around the blinking characters?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made a single screen immitating a classic Commodore 64 screen.
I'm getting a border around the blinking characters. How could I ommit this? I haven't defined one.

```
<script>
    ctx.font = "21px Commodore64Angled";
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground1;
    for (var i = 0; i < chars[0].length; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(chars[0].substr(i, 1).toUpperCase(), xCharCnt * 4 + xCharCnt * i, yCharCnt * 4 + (0 + 1) * 2 * yCharCnt - 2);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground2;
    for (var j = 1; j < 8; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars[j].length; i++)
        ctx.fillText(chars[j].substr(i, 1).toUpperCase(), xCharCnt * 4 + xCharCnt * i, yCharCnt * 4 + (j + 1) * 2 * yCharCnt - 2);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground1;
    for (var j = 8; j < 11; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars[j].length; i++)
        ctx.fillText(chars[j].substr(i, 1).toUpperCase(), xCharCnt * 4 + xCharCnt * i, yCharCnt * 4 + (j + 1) * 2 * yCharCnt - 2);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground3;
    for (var i = 0; i < chars[11].length; i++) {
        ctx.fillText(chars[11].substr(i, 1).toUpperCase(), xCharCnt * 4 + xCharCnt * i, yCharCnt * 4 + (j + 1) * 2 * yCharCnt - 2);
    }
    // Zum Blinken bringen
    var backgr = background;
    var foregr = foreground3;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (foregr == foreground3) {
            backgr = foreground2;
            foregr = background;
        }
        else {
            backgr = background;
            foregr = foreground3;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = backgr;
        ctx.fillRect(xCharCnt * (4 + 5) + 1, yCharCnt * 28 - yCharCnt - 1, xCharCnt * 29, yCharCnt);
        for (var i = 0; i < chars[11].length; i++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = foregr;
            ctx.fillText(chars[11].substr(i, 1).toUpperCase(), xCharCnt * 4 + xCharCnt * i, yCharCnt * 4 + (j + 1) * 2 * yCharCnt - 2);
        }
    }, 300);
</script>
```

Have a look at:

```
ctx.fillRect(xCharCnt * (4 + 5) + 1, yCharCnt * 27 - 1, xCharCnt * 29, yCharCnt);
```

I'd be thankful for any idea. :)

Comment: Note: I'd want to present you the hole bunch of code so you could've easily test it within your browser, but stackoverflow didn't let me, saying it'd be too much code compared to my explanation. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own: I set the renderings into their respective if construct and defined to render one pixel more in each direction so that the black borders I've got, got overwrote. Here is the result:

```
ctx.fillRect(xCharCnt * (4 + 5) + 1 - 1, yCharCnt * 27 - 1 - 1, xCharCnt * 29 + 2, yCharCnt + 2);
```